# Simplifying std::transform for single vector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, implicit-conversion, template-argument-deduction

I want to write a simple function to simplify `std::transform` for a transformation on a single vector.

What I've got so far:

```
template<typename T>
void transform(std::vector<T> &vec, const std::function<T(const T &)> &fun) {
  std::transform(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::begin(vec), fun);
}
```

Now when I want to use this function I can write, for example:

```
transform<int>(vec, my_function);
```

But I would prefer if I could just use

```
transform(vec, my_function);
```

Is there a way to adjust my code to automatically infer the type?

error:

> ```
> no matching function for call to 'transform' and note: candidate template ignored:
> could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' 
> against '(lambda at [...]
> ```

Comment: @songyuanyao I get `error: no matching function for call to 'transform'` and `note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (const type-parameter-0-0 &)>' against '(lambda at [...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're using lambda as the argument; lambda could be converted to `std::function`, but implicit conversion won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), that's why it fails.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

You can use `static_cast` explicitly to convert the lambda to `std::function` when passing it, or stop using `std::function`. e.g.

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void transform(std::vector<T> &vec, F fun) {
  std::transform(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), std::begin(vec), fun);
}
```

Comment: Works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use `std::function` argument, if for some reason you need it, is to disable type deduction for `T` in it by moving `T` into a non-deduced context:

```
template<typename T>
struct Identity { using Type = T; };

template<typename T>
using Id = typename Identity<T>::Type;

template<typename T>
void transform(std::vector<T>&, const std::function<Id<T>(const Id<T>&)>&);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over-constraining both arguments, and try to use template-deduction and implicit-conversion at the same time for the second, which cannot work. Dispensing with that, and optionally using SFINAE, makes things work properly, more efficient and flexible:

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;

template <class Range, class F>
auto transform(Range&& range, F f)
noexcept(noexcept(std::transform(begin(range), end(range), begin(range), f)))
-> decltype(std::transform(begin(range), end(range), begin(range), f))
{ return std::transform(begin(range), end(range), begin(range), f); }
```

Yes, the function-object is copied. If you don't want that, simply pass a `std::reference_wrapper` using `std::ref`, just like for the standard-library algorithms.